# Symfony Doctrine update command doesn't create a foreign key in unidirectional many-to-one association

Tags: symfony, doctrine, synchronization, foreign-keys

I have following issue - I have one table, `object_types` in MySQL database and two Entities - `Object` and `ObjectType` in my Symfony 3.2 project. I have just synchronized the object types and now I want to do the same with objects with `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --complete` command but it doesn't create a foreign key between tables.

Here is  the `Object` class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Object
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="object")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ObjectRepository")
 */
class Object
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="objectID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $ID;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_typeID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ObjectType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_typeID", referencedColumnName="object_typeID")
     */
    private $typeID;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_title", type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_path", type="text")
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_added", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $added;

    ....
}
```

ObjectType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ObjectType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="object_types")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ObjectTypeRepository")
 */
class ObjectType
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_typeID", type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $typeID;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_type_name", type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $typeName;
```

How to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

**ManyToOne**

```
   /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ObjectType", inversedBy="object")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_typeID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $typeID;
```

**OneToMany**

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Object", mappedBy="typeID")
     */
    protected $object;
```

Your entities should be as below.

**Object**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Object
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="object")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ObjectRepository")
 */
class Object
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="objectID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $ID;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ObjectType", inversedBy="object")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_typeID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $typeID;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_title", type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_path", type="text")
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_added", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $added;

    ....
}
```

**ObjectType**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ObjectType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="object_types")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ObjectTypeRepository")
 */
class ObjectType
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_type_name", type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $typeName;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Object", mappedBy="typeID")
     */
    protected $object;
```

Hopefully it should work fine.